Unknown wire to board connector
i have a wire to board connector for a rice cooker & need to replicate it.
I have no idea who makes it...it seems to resemble a JST XA but not certain.
Pitch is 2.54 2 pin.






Please post a picture of its mate, the one this one is connected to.

i added 2 pics of the plug

My Identiconn utility identifies that as an HCTL - HC-XHB.

{Source: HCTL}
I know that your part is marked ZJT, but that company has no online presence, so I can't link to it. Many Chinese manufacturers duplicate each-other's connectors, including HCTL.
The pitch is 2.5 mm, not 2.54 mm.

very cool application you made.
What company has the marking ZJT (& is it Z J T ?)

Ningbo ZJT Electric Co., Ltd

Looks like a normal JST XH-2 just with a latch. The ones with a latch are less common but I guess you can try finding them on AliExpress. However if you just want it to work you can use a normal JST XH connector.
